# docker version number confusion: 17.06 vs 1.13?

Tags: docker

I am confused by the version number of `docker`

Some documentation refers to version numbers like `17.06`  E.g. (from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/))

> However, starting with Docker 17.06, you can also use `--mount` with standalone containers

But some other documentation refers to version number like `1.13`  E.g. (from [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#container-diagram))

> Note: version 1.13 or higher is required

Was the version numbering convention changed at some point in time?

Comment: *"Was the version numbering convention changed at some point in time?"* Yes: https://blog.docker.com/2017/03/docker-enterprise-edition/. If you click on the version drop-down in the docs, you can see that it goes 1.12, 1.13, 17.03, 17.06.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> 17.03.0-ce (2017-03-01)
>
> IMPORTANT: Starting with this release, Docker is on a monthly release cycle and uses a new YY.MM versioning scheme to reflect this. Two channels are available: monthly and quarterly. Any given monthly release will only receive security and bugfixes until the next monthly release is available. Quarterly releases receive security and bugfixes for 4 months after initial release. This release includes bugfixes for 1.13.1 but there are no major feature additions and the API version stays the same. Upgrading from Docker 1.13.1 to 17.03.0 is expected to be simple and low-risk.

It was changed from 17.03. Which is march release for this year

https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/17.03/

Comment: I just got prompted for a Docker update on my Macbook, I have 18.06.0 installed, and it's prompting me to update to 2.0.0.0-beta1. Have they gone back to the old versioning scheme?

Comment: Aha - Docker Engine is 18.09.0, but Docker Desktop is 2.0.0.0. The latter includes the former.

Comment: Thanks very much! Updating some old hosts and I couldn't find those notes about the numbering changes anywhere but here!

Comment: The answer does not share from which weblink/document/artifact reference its excerpt is taken. Can someone please share this?

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh, added the link to the answer

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani. I think it best that Docker clear up confusion around what's going on with their version-and-release-management process: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/fv65v9/docker_version_scheme_what_happened_to_release/fmi5ipl/.